# my dom is not reflecting my model updated value, updationg is done by a function which is cal on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
app.controller('thumbnailController', function ($scope) {
    debugger
    $scope.customers = [
                  { name: 'ave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
                  { name: 'amie Riley', city: 'Phoenix' }

    ];
    $scope.SortCustomer = function (searchitem) {
        $scope.customers = [
              { name: 'ave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
              { name: 'amie Riley', city: 'Phoenix' }
        ];
        if (searchitem != 'all') {
            var filter = [];
            var items = $scope.customers;
            //  $scope.angular.forEach
            var i = 0;
            for (i; i < 7; i++) {
                if (items[i].name[0] === searchitem) {
                    console.log('pushing');
                    filter.push(items[i]);
                }
            }
            $scope.customers = filter;  // I have update my customers list hear but it not reflecting on dom
        }

    };
})
```

Comment: Honestly your question is very incomplete.

Comment: Can you explain more elaborately what the problem is exactly? Also, please provide some jsfiddle/plunker to help understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

with a method like that on scope you should use it with `ng-click`

```
<button ng-click="SortCustomer()">click me</button>
```

although here in JS instead of passing searchitem as parameter you should use model assigned to whatever input you are using

```
$scope.SortCustomer = function (searchitem) {
```

I'll be able to answer more specific as soon as you do a plunker or jsfiddle

Cheers